# Paragraphs Grid module settings ignored

Tags: paragraphs

I'm using the [Paragraphs grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_grid) module to display multiple paragraph entities in a grid. I followed the [getting-started video](https://youtu.be/onU1E2Z6Jvc) and created a test page (see below for the source it generated), but it seems to be ignoring the grid settings I've chosen. I started by setting my first paragraph to full-width, and the next two to "2 columns" as shown in the video.

Looking at the elements in Chrome's inspector, the only classes set on these paragraphs contain only seemingly non-grid-related types: `paragraph paragraph--type--basic-paragraph paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--id--14`. The source from what I can tell contains no grid-related markup or classes.

What could be causing the module not to behave as expected?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/  og: http://ogp.me/ns#  rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#  schema: http://schema.org/  sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#  sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#  skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#  xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# ">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Logo.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://wilmettewatch.com/test-page" />
<link rel="shortlink" href="https://wilmettewatch.com/node/10" />
<link rel="revision" href="https://wilmettewatch.com/test-page" />

    <title>Test page | Wilmette Watch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_P_uhd9uFXz_crbPUanUYUW0d_XlQPVaT82ZcQeKjcms.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_r6feGj8LSqa2_hg-aKcSQjNSMnct7c5IB_xVe2Y_oiQ.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_gudi_owL-2YsUCuS-NBbZM4ARsPDs4DIxZH-Z_rFxFM.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_Y4H_4BqmgyCtG7E7YdseTs2qvy9C34c51kBamDdgark.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One" />

    
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="/sites/default/files/js/js_VtafjXmRvoUgAzqzYTA3Wrjkx9wcWhjP0G4ZnnqRamA.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body class="layout-no-sidebars page-node-10 path-node node--type-page">
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">
      Skip to main content
    </a>
    
      <div class="dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas" data-off-canvas-main-canvas>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="page">
    <header id="header" class="header" role="banner" aria-label="Site header">
                      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbar-main">
                              <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home" class="navbar-brand">
              <img src="/Logo90.png" alt="Home" class="img-fluid d-inline-block align-top" />
            Wilmette Watch
    </a>
    

                                          </nav>
          </header>
          <div class="highlighted">
        <aside class="container-fluid section clearfix" role="complementary">
            <div data-drupal-messages-fallback class="hidden"></div>


        </aside>
      </div>
            <div id="main-wrapper" class="layout-main-wrapper clearfix">
              <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
          
          <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left clearfix">
              <main class="main-content col order-last" id="content" role="main">
                <section class="section">
                  <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
                    <div id="block-wilmettewatch-page-title" class="block block-core block-page-title-block">
  
    
      <div class="content">
      
  <h1 class="title"><span property="schema:name" class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">Test page</span>
</h1>


    </div>
  </div>
<div id="block-wilmettewatch-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block">
  
    
      <div class="content">
      

<article data-history-node-id="10" role="article" about="/test-page" typeof="schema:WebPage" class="node node--type-page node--view-mode-full clearfix">
    <div class="node__content clearfix">
    
<div class="field field--name-field-body field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden">


  <div>
          <div class="field__item">







<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--basic-paragraph paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--id--14">
  <div class="paragraph__column">
    
            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body-text field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><p>Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? </p>

<p>Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? </p>

<p>Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? Why isn't this working? Also, where's the summary? </p></div>
      
  </div>
</div>
</div>
          <div class="field__item">







<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--image paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--id--16">
  <div class="paragraph__column">
    
            <div class="field field--name-field-image field--type-image field--label-hidden field__item">  <img src="/sites/default/files/2020-05/Logo90.png" width="90" height="90" alt="ww" typeof="foaf:Image" />

</div>
      
  </div>
</div>
</div>
          <div class="field__item">







<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--basic-paragraph paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--id--17">
  <div class="paragraph__column">
    
            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-body-text field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><p>More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? More text here. How does it look? </p></div>
      
  </div>
</div>
</div>
          <div class="field__item">
  <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--figure paragraph--view-mode--paragraphsgridtest landscape-photo">
          <figure class="article-figure">
        

        <figcaption> </figcaption>
      </figure>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>

</div>



  </div>
</article>

    </div>
  </div>


                </section>
              </main>
                                  </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        <footer class="site-footer">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                            </div>
          </footer>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

    
    <script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","currentPath":"node\/10","currentPathIsAdmin":false,"isFront":false,"currentLanguage":"en"},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","suppressDeprecationErrors":true,"user":{"uid":0,"permissionsHash":"adf817ccf74d3c1df22405e040258050699cca41f71f33f2578ae311d9993ecb"}}</script>
<script src="/sites/default/files/js/js_ZjI08cC2AozgNCXBnZB5IuaaWKY0ilO1iDRLKNND_-E.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/default/files/js/js_qgveMN0dDH03r-aWKzJyg-TqpRxn6ZJGYKDT9jdAlpk.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like a bug report or documentation request to a module hosted on drupal.org and therefore must be reported there to be fixed.

Comment: There would be a substantial number of questions on here that would be closed if you were to apply a "documentation request" criterion to them. I'm not sure that's a valid reason to close a question, the fact that the answer isn't well documented by a product. And if it ends up being a defect in the module, [I'm not sure that's a valid reason to close a question either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358440/close-a-question-by-bug-fix-or-update); the correct answer being "this is  a documented bug."

Comment: @glenviewjeff Bug reports, and to some degree documentation requests, are indeed off topic here (please see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for full details). I'm not convinced this is necessarily either, though. If it does end up being a bug report, it'll be closed as such, as we don't want to fracture the larger Drupal community's attention away from the place where a bug would be discussed and fixed (i.e. the issue tracker on d.o.)

Comment: At best it's premature to close this question as a defect report, and further strikes me as highly unlikely that this is a defect in a mature well-maintained and stable module--that it would be fundamentally broken without being marked as such.

Comment: Yeah I'm inclined to agree, but I'm also positive that leymannx cast their vote in good faith and with a good knowledge of Drupal and Drupal Answers, so I guess there's a bit of subjectivity at work here. Either way, that's why closing takes more than one vote :)

Comment: If the module is not adding the CSS classes you are expecting, it can be either a bug in that module, the documentation that doesn't explain well how the module works, the module has not been set as it should, or there is a misunderstanding on how the module should work. In any case, _What could be causing the module not to behave as espected?_  seems a bit too broad.

Comment: @kiamlaluno how would you propose that I word the question given that I have no idea yet what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's neither a matter of wording nor doing anything wrong. it's just that _I don't see the CSS classes that I would expect to see applied from the module. What could cause the module not to apply those CSS classes?_ is a little too broad. You need to debug what is happening. Once you have more details, you can add them to the question. We cannot exclude there are other modules causing issues, nor can we exclude there are other factors that cause what you noticed. That is something you need to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paragraphs won't render markup for a particular content type if you don't set the format for its Paragraphs fields to `Paragraphs Grid (rendered entity)` as shown below.

Remember to make sure that if you have any custom display settings, that you also go to their tab and set the Paragraphs fields similarly. If you have the format set to the default (Rendered entity), Paragraphs will not generate the necessary markup.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `Go to the Administer page of your node type (e.g. /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display) and select the „Paragraphs Grid formatter“ for the Paragraphs field (Type: Entity Reference Revisions).` – This instruction can be be found on the project's public description page and in its README.

Comment: Correct. The problem was that this wasn't done for the full content display settings.